# Change base language of Windows 8 Installer

Tags: windows-8, language

I have access to Dreamspark and Windows 8. When I picked the version I picked English which is fine, but it is US English however I realised I should have picked UK English instead. You are only allowed one version so i cannot switch it.

Now, I can change the language pack later to UK English but in the language bar US English is always listed and seems impossible to remove and system restore reverts to US English.

Is there a way to fully change the base language to UK in the installer, so in effect makin the installer offer US and UK English, or just UK English as if I had chosen the correct version?

Comment: This likely can't be solved without access to a different .iso image.

Answer (score 1):

Get the EN-GB Language Packs:

32Bit: http://fg.v4.download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2013/09/lp_43e709fc9932e26431ff87e163daaaeae15677eb.cab

64Bit: http://fg.v4.download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2013/09/lp_55c5ff4da1d83ae6f4ebd1f8c020cb80ceda7da8.cab

and rename the file to LP.mlc and make a double click to install it. In the control panel chaneg the default language to EN-GB.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2607607